# I have a controller in express that needs to call two times to mongoDB but fails

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following controller

```
const Rutina = require("../models/rutina");
const Ejercicio = require("../models/ejercicio");
const { StatusCodes } = require("http-status-codes");
const { BadRequestError, NotFoundError } = require("../errors");

const createRutina = async (req, res) => {
  const { id_usuario, nombre, dias } = req.body;
  const ejercicios = await Ejercicio.find({});
  const diasModificados = await Promise.all(
    dias.map(async (dia) => {
      const ejerciciosModificados = await Promise.all(
        dia.ejercicios.map(async (ejercicio) => {
          const ejercicioDB = ejercicios.find(
            (ejercicioDB) => ejercicioDB.id_ejercicio === ejercicio.id_ejercicio
          );
          ejercicio.nombre = ejercicioDB.nombre;
          ejercicio.descripcion = ejercicioDB.descripcion;
          ejercicio.leyenda = ejercicioDB.leyenda;
          ejercicio.tipo = ejercicioDB.tipo;
          return ejercicio;
        })
      );
      dia.ejercicios = ejerciciosModificados;
      return dia;
    })
  );
  console.log(diasModificados)
  const rutina = await Rutina.create({
    id_usuario,
    nombre,
    dias: diasModificados,
  });
  res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).json(rutina);
};
```

When I make a console.log of diasModificados like you see in the code the days have the modifications that i did are there, but when i create the rutina and send it in my res the modifications are not there.
The modifications are add name,description,leyenda and tipo from the ejercicio on DB to the ejercicio that i am going to send

I make promises, use awaits, make function apart but anything works.

Ejercicio Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const EjercicioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nombre: String,
  descripcion: String,
  video: String,
  leyenda: {
    type: String,
  },
  tipo: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["pesas", "cardio"],
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Ejercicio", EjercicioSchema);
```

Rutina Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const RutinaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id_usuario: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: [true, "Agregale a un usuario esta rutina"]
    },
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Agregale un nombre a la Rutina"]
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: () => new Date(+new Date()),
    },
    dias: [
        {
            dia: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, "Ingresa los dias de esta rutina"]
            },
            calorias_a_quemar:{
                type: Number,
                required: [true,"Ingresa las calorias que se queman en este dia"]
            },
            musculo:{
                type: String,
                required: [true, "Ingresa el musculo que trabaja"]
            },
            ejercicios:[
                {
                    ejercicio_id:{
                        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                    },
                    repeticiones:{
                        type: Number
                    },
                    series: {
                        type: Number
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Rutina", RutinaSchema);Ï
```

Comment: Please add on schema also so it will be helpful for writing solution

Comment: I add it thanks for the advice